# Release a new app as an update on app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, updates

I have an app on the App Store that I no longer have access to it's source code. Can I make a new app in Xcode and release it as an update to the existing users of the old app?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as long as the bundle id is the same, it will be an update.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you